# How can a recursive call in a for loop be optimized?

Tags: c, recursion, optimization

I would like to know how a recursive function called in a loop of its own definition could be optimized like a tail call so as not to suffer from performance and stack size.

Typically, with pseudo code:

```
fun example(x):
    if (something):
        return // Stop the recursion
    else:
        for (/*...*/):
            example() // Recursive call
```

For a concrete example, I would like to know how to apply such an optimization on the following program, found [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/):

```
// C program to print all permutations with duplicates allowed 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 

/* Function to swap values at two pointers */
void swap(char *x, char *y) 
{ 
    char temp; 
    temp = *x; 
    *x = *y; 
    *y = temp; 
} 

/* Function to print permutations of string 
   This function takes three parameters: 
   1. String 
   2. Starting index of the string 
   3. Ending index of the string. */
void permute(char *a, int l, int r) 
{ 
   int i; 
   if (l == r) 
     printf("%s\n", a); 
   else
   { 
       for (i = l; i <= r; i++) 
       { 
          swap((a+l), (a+i)); 
          permute(a, l+1, r); // Recursive call to be optimized
          swap((a+l), (a+i));
       } 
   } 
} 

/* Driver program to test above functions */
int main() 
{ 
    char str[] = "ABC"; 
    int n = strlen(str); 
    permute(str, 0, n-1); 
    return 0; 
}
```

If the recursion becomes too deep, there is a risk of stack overflow. So how could we avoid that with this style of recursive functions (if possible, without drastically modifying the algorithm)?

Comment: The tail call optimization requires that the **recursive call happens at the tail position**. Yours does not.

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm just asking how to proceed in order to optimize the style of case I present.

Comment: You can not, a function is tail recursive when calling itself is the last pending thing to do, in your case there is another operation (`swap`)  pending, furthermore it is called in a loop, so no, assume that all vars (sizeof(int) * 3) must be copied and accumulated in the stack for each call.

Comment: The recursion in your example is essentially a tree traversal of the permutations and printing only the leaves. You can do the same with tail recursion if you add position information regarding where you currently are in the tree traversal. That said, it's just easier to do iteratively.

Comment: Okay, I see. So, if there's no way to optimize it, how can we rewrite it iteratively?

Comment: Are you having performance problems? Have you profiled the code?

Comment: No, but it is not a question of whether or not to optimize the code. I just want to know its optimized form of recursivity or, as it is apparently not feasible here, its non-recursive rewriting.

Comment: @bruno Not true.

Comment: @Nelfeal why not true?, it depends on how long is the string, are we talking of few bytes, KBs, MBs? reading/writing to the stack is very very fast even using a lot of iterations, calling `malloc` is very very expensive

Comment: @DavidRanieri Why would an iterative algorithm need to copy the string if a recursive one does not? You can literally emulate the recursive algorithm with a custom stack in an iterative one. No need for any allocation, except maybe for the custom stack itself (but I believe you actually don't need one).

Comment: @Nelfeal Read again: _the iterative version uses **dynamic allocations**_

Comment: @DavidRanieri Did you read the answer? There you have an iterative version without dynamic allocations.

Comment: @klutt Yes, I have read an upvoted the answer (nice answer), but Bruno was talking about dynamic allocations (`malloc`) and Nelfeal claimed not true, that was my point.

Comment: @DavidRanieri bruno said *"the iterative version uses dynamic allocations"* which is a weird claim. There are several ways of doing this iteratively, and it can be done without dynamic allocations. So there's no "THE iterative version". This phrasing could also mean a specific iterative version, but I cannot see such in either the question or the comments.

Comment: @DavidRanieri Not sure I understand you. I mentioned copying the string because that's what you would use the *dynamic allocations* for. Or at least that's what I got from you mentioning the length of the string.

Comment: @bruno For what it's worth, I actually do think my answer's code is more optimized than OP's. Emulating recursion with a custom stack might not be, but I doubt it would be much worse than actual recursion.

Comment: @Netlfeal what I mean is: a recursive function can be very fast even if not tail recusive optimized, your approach is even faster, but again: your replied "Not true" to a comment talking about "dynamic allocation" vs recursive.

Comment: @DavidRanieri Oh I see now. You thought my reply was refering to the "better to use your current version" part, when it was in fact refering to the whole sentence, and in particular the "the iterative version uses dynamic allocations and copies" part. For sure, a version using dynamic allocations and copies may be worse than OP's, but my point was that the premise (that you need allocations and copies) is false, and so is the entire sentence.

Comment: @Nelfeal that is :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not produce the exact same output, but is an iterative way of printing all permutations of a string. Adapted from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation).

```
void reverse(char *a, int l, int r)
{
    while ((l != r) && (l != --r)) {
        swap(a+(l++), a+r);
    }
}

bool next_permutation(char *a, int l, int r)
{
    if (l == r) return false;
    int i = r;
    if (l == --i) return false;

    while (true) {
        int i1 = i;
        if (a[--i] < a[i1]) {
            int i2 = r;
            while (!(a[i] < a[--i2]))
                ;
            swap(a+i, a+i2);
            reverse(a, i1, r);
            return true;
        }
        if (i == l) {
            reverse(a, l, r);
            return false;
        }
    }
}

void permute(char *a, int l, int r) 
{
    do {
        printf("%s\n", a);
    } while(next_permutation(a, l, r+1));
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b401ef20f623625e)